# R: Call a Specific Column

Tags: r

I am trying to pickup specific value by row name and column name.
I have a df look like this and I am not allowed to change the column name.

```
    OA  OB  OC  OD
OA  -   E   C   G
OB  C   -   J   L
OC  A   A   -   A
OD  A   B   B   A
```

For example, row=OA and col=OB will return E, row=OD and col=OB will return B. 
I have tried `df["OA", "OB"]` which is in below, but it didn't return anything.

Comment: If you work with a data.frame rather than a tbl_df, then df["OA", "OB"]` will work as desired. you can convert to a data.frame using `as.data.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Are you allowed to subset using coordinates?

Such as...

```
 OAOB<-df[1,2]
 ##this will give you the value "E"
```

Use the name of your df, and then [row,col] coordinates

Comment: df[1,2] gave me

# A tibble: 1 x 1
     OA
  <chr>
1     -

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the `data.table` library?

```
#Opens data.table if not already open
require(data.table)

#Just creates the data as above
OA <- c("-", "C", "A", "A")
OB <- c("E", "-", "A", "B")
OC <- c("C", "J", "-", "B")
OD <- c("G", "L", "A", "A")

#Puts it all together
DT <- as.data.table(cbind(OA, OB, OC, OD))

#Makes the proper row names
row.names(DT) <- c("OA", "OB", "OC", "OD")

View(DT)

#Row OA, Col OB
DT[1,2]

#Row OD, Col OB
DT[4,2]
```

See if that works for you! Just copy and paste that right into your console.